# How to handling any error of page loading while doing login verification fo 50 users in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Let's say We have to do login verification for 50 users in selenium WebDriver.

While doing it, some how some error occurred like :
--Page not loading
--404 error
--Unexpected error.

How can i handle these scenarios and continue to test remaining users login verification ?

I am using Java.

Comment: Depends on how your code is written. You could use a try/catch and throw an exception when 404 is found in the page text, log it, and move to the next user.

Answer (score 0):

You'd handle them just like you would other tests.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
username.sendKeys("user");
password.sendKeys("pass");
loginButton.click();
assertTrue(pageText.contains("404"));
```

Ideally though, you should split those up into 50 different test cases individually to maintain independence, and reduce test times.

Comment: He's asking how to handle the case when there is a 404 and keep on testing. The code you have written is going to fail most of the time (whenever 404 does NOT exist) and will likely cause the script to fail... depending on how it's configured, e.g. TestNG will fail the execution on failed assert.

Comment: hence pseudo. just giving the user an idea of how to handle it

Comment: Thanks for the answering on my query.
But my query is :
i don't know which error will come. my script is testing 18th user now in middle any of the error occurred. How do I will handle it and again wants to test with the same user, because it didn't get test yet. application has inconsistent behavior.

Comment: split your tests up.. read the "ideally though." part.  keep your tests independent of each other

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling such a scenario would be , checking for the presence of the element before performing any actions such as click or sendKeys.

The documentation can be found at : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

You could make the test, parametrised (aka data driven) ,assuming that the user login data changes and not the actual flow. 
Docs : https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Hope this helps you.